# What nationality is Bane?

Tags: character, the-dark-knight-rises

It has been clearly established that Ra's Al Ghul & Talia Al Ghul are Moroccan. And it is assumed that The Pit is in Morocco.

Does this mean that we should assume Bane is also Moroccan? Or is it just coincidence that he was in a Moroccan prison and involved with two Moroccans?

Comment: He is definatly morrocan......

Comment: @bob Have you any proof for this statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An article written by NBC has the following quote.

> **DC Comics describes Bane’s father as a British mercenary and his mother a rebel from the Caribbean. His life spent in a jail on the fictional Caribbean Island of Santa Prisca, a seemingly Spanish name.**

So basically Bane is half British, half Caribbean which would explain why he is so tanned yet still speaks perfect English.

Link to the article [here](http://nbclatino.tumblr.com/post/13457338255/debate-is-batmans-archrival-bane-latino)

Comment: But on the other hand this article about the comics speaks about a Caribbean prison (and maybe mixes in motives of *Talia*'s movie version, being the child of a mercenary). So I don't think this can be taken as a real explanation for the movie version of *Bane*. But at least one could see the parallel between Caribbean identity and prison, which would speak for him being at least half Moroccan instead of Caribbean (which surely makes him tanned, too).

Comment: In the TDKR, the prison was in the Middle East. This answer is clearly incorrect, as it deals with the comic version, not the movie version as asked.

Answer (score 18):

First of all, there is [this article from NBC](http://nbclatino.tumblr.com/post/13457338255/debate-is-batmans-archrival-bane-latino) (that is also referenced in another answer) which says that Bane's nationality/ethnicity is half British and half Caribbean:

> DC Comics describes Bane’s father as a British mercenary and his
>   mother a rebel from the Caribbean. His life spent in a jail on the
>   fictional Caribbean Island of Santa Prisca, a seemingly Spanish name.

But they fail to set this into context with a movie franchise that **has made [extensive changes to the characters](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/23914/49) of its source material** (though they themselves mention some of the changes to his character in the movie, including the casting of a non-Latino actor). For example they speak of a ***Caribbean* prison** (which it wasn't in the movie) and the comic character seems to **include elements from Talia's movie character**, being the child of a mercenary (while Ra's Al Ghul isn't a mercenary in the comics).

So all in all I don't think this article or the comic source material it references can be used as an explanation for the character of Bane as depicted in *The Dark Knight Rises*, at least **not a ono-to-one explanation**.

---

**But to come back to the actual question what nationality Bane was then**, one could at least use the fact that there is most probably a connection between the comic Bane being half-Carribean and spending his life in a Caribbean prison. So if we set this into context with the movie placing the location of the prison in Morocco ([which isn't 100% clear though](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/3454/49)), it is a **very reasonable deduction that the Bane from the movie is indeed to some degree Moroccan** (which would also make him look tanned, albeit not after growing up in the pit, though). But I think apart from that we cannot draw any other conclusions, as his backstory is not mentioned in the movie and **the comics fail to provide an explanation** because of the above mentioned contradictions to the movie.